# Не удается отобразить компоненту React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

Добрый день всем! Начал изучать React, для первой своей работы выбрал Material UI v1.0. Там оказалась подходящая мне компонента Media Cards https://material-ui-next.com/demos/cards/
Требовалось создать столько карточек, сколько у меня автомобилей.
Добавил компоненту и начал получать ошибки на connect, то на на withStyles.
Последние ошибки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После долгих мучений имею следующий код:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import {fetchAuto} from 'actions';
import {getAutos} from 'selectors';

const styles = {
    card: {
        maxWidth: 345,
    },
    media: {
        height: 200,
    },
};

class listAuto extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.fetchAuto();
    }

    renderCardAuto (auto, index, props) {
        const {classes} = props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Card className={classes.card} key={index}>
                    <CardMedia
                        className={classes.media}
                        image={auto.image}
                        title="Contemplative Reptile"
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
                            {auto.name}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p">
                            {auto.description}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small" color="primary">
                            Share
                        </Button>
                        <Button size="small" color="primary">
                            Learn More
                        </Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render () {
        const {autos} = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                {autos.map((auto, index) => this.renderCardAuto(auto, index, this.props))}
            </div>
        )
    };

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    autos: getAutos(state)
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
fetchAuto
};


//export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(listAuto)
export default compose(
withStyles(styles, {
    name: 'listAuto',
}),
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(listAuto);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: как минимум уВас имя компонента с маленькой буквы написано, в реакте это вызывает ошибку.

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!!